# Remove paragraphs and saving everything to one line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Hi there I am not sure how to explain, I have this problem. Currently I have some text as shown below:

```
 picture gallery 
    see also 
    adaptation
    ecology
    extreme environment clothing
    extremophile
    lexen life in extreme environments
    natural environment
    references 
    "extreme environment" microbial life np nd web 16 may 2013
    feminism and gis refers to the use of geographic information system gis for feminist research and also how women influence gis at technological stages feminist gis research is aware of power differences in social and economic realms
     history
```

My question is how do i make it till I get the result like this for example:

```
picture gallery see also adaptation ecology extreme environment clothing extremophile lexen life in extreme environments natural environment references "extreme environment" microbial life np nd web 16 may 2013 feminism and gis refers to the use of geographic information system gis for feminist research and also how women influence gis at technological stages feminist gis research is aware of power differences in social and economic realms
```

I am not sure what this is called but so far the solution  I have found is removing all blank spaces which is not what I need.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Is a file first, or just some text?

Comment: You might correct the result by adding history back in - or indicate explicitly, that this shall be remove from input (last word or history esp. or ... ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes it's a file.

Comment: Ok, better late, than never :) - I updated my answer. This should be as good as it gets (when the file's content does not exceed available RAM ...)

Answer (score 4):

If it's a file:

```
text = file('path/to/your/file.txt').read()
new_text = text.replace('\n', ' ')
print(new_text) # this will have no new lines
with open('output.txt', 'wr') as out:
    out.write(new_text) #this will write it to a file
```

You could also use regex, like PJSCopeland said:

```
import re
s = "Example String \n more example string"
replaced = re.sub('\s+', ' ', s)
print replaced
```

Dilettant's solution is concise, correct and also faster than using regex (by my measure), so I recommend that as a best solution:

```
filtered = ' '.join(text.strip().split())
```

Comment: Would the first one replace the spaces after the newlines as well? And would the second replace all instances as it stands, or does it need the `g` flag?

Comment: The second one would not require the g flag. As per your first question no, it actually needs to remove multiple spaces afterwards, good catch @PJSCopeland.

Answer (score 2):

Please note, that the result given in the answer is quite creative at the right margin, it dropped history from input data ;-) **Update**: Latest comment indicates, data comes from file, thus updated answer.

Taking this as a small unwanted glitch, I suggest to **neither** use regular expressions **nor** replace. Simply do the strip-split-join transformation in one go like so (assuming the text is in file `in.txt` in folder where you invoe the script):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

with open('in.txt', 'rt') as f:
    filtered = ' '.join(f.read().strip().split())
```

Or - if already in variable (and with expectation and comparison as minimal test):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

text = '''picture gallery 
    see also 
    adaptation
    ecology
    extreme environment clothing
    extremophile
    lexen life in extreme environments
    natural environment
    references 
    "extreme environment" microbial life np nd web 16 may 2013
    feminism and gis refers to the use of geographic information system gis for feminist research and also how women influence gis at technological stages feminist gis research is aware of power differences in social and economic realms
     history 
'''

expected = (
    'picture gallery see also adaptation ecology extreme environment'
    ' clothing extremophile lexen life in extreme environments'
    ' natural environment references "extreme environment" microbial'
    ' life np nd web 16 may 2013 feminism and gis refers to the use'
    ' of geographic information system gis for feminist research and'
    ' also how women influence gis at technological stages feminist'
    ' gis research is aware of power differences in social and'
    ' economic realms history')

filtered = ' '.join(text.strip().split())

assert filtered == expected
```

And in case you need a newline at the end of that "one line" result, you could write instead:

```
filtered = '%s\n' % (' '.join(text.strip().split()),)
```

or

```
filtered = ' '.join(text.strip().split()) + '\n'
```

In that case of course the assert or expected variable should be changed in sync ;-)

This should be also a logically clear solution. Regular expressions are often tempting, but if the result is feasible with simple split-join pipelines like this one, they induce some runtime complexity (and another language embedded).

Just measure with above setup and an adapted one for the regex:

```
print 'strip-split-join:  ', ['%0.4f' % round(z, 4) for z in timeit.Timer("filtered = ' '.join(text.strip().split())", setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)]
print 're.sub("\s+", " "):', ['%0.4f' % round(z, 4) for z in timeit.Timer("filtered = replaced = re.sub('\s+', ' ', text)", setup=setup_re).repeat(7, 1000)]
```

this gives (on my machine):

```
strip-split-join:   ['0.0043', '0.0045', '0.0047', '0.0046', '0.0043', '0.0040', '0.0045']
re.sub("\s+", " "): ['0.0265', '0.0254', '0.0246', '0.0248', '0.0238', '0.0255', '0.0266']
```

so the regex solution is slower by approx. a factor of 5.

Comment: Neither of my suggested solutions "dropped history" to my knowledge. My first recommendation does leave a lot of nasty spaces. The regex works fine, it just leaves one extra space at the end `expected == replaced[:-1]` was true using it. I'd be curious to know which solution is faster -- the regex or this. It is nice that it's one line :)

Comment: @rofls: I think it is logically more concise i.e. explicit and faster by a factor of 5 or so - please cf. my updated answer. Considering that the OP apears to be a novice on her/his way of learning python, regex is a complicated and mostly frustrating experience eg. when some typo slips in, escaping needed etc. When bread and butter solutions are known, it should be a better situation to then attack more complicated tasks with regular expressions - later (IMO).

Comment: Dilettant this solution is fastest. Not by a factor of five (by my test), but it is fastest so I will recommend it. Then again there was the overhead of importing the `re` module in our test. Anyway I doubt OP needs the fastest, and I agree your solution is clearer; so that's probably most important :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `/\s+/g` (every instance of at least one white-space character) with `" "`. (I'm not familiar with Python, unfortunately, so I don't know what the method call would be.)

Comment: `re.sub()`, from the `re` module :)